# Prove that chromatic number $\geq \frac{V^2}{V^2-2E}$

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Let us have a simple graph G. (That means no loops and no multiple edges)

Prove that $\chi \geq  \frac{V^2}{V^2-2E}$

I found the task in the book by John Bondy "Graph Theory with Applications" (Task 8.1.1)

The preliminary theorems didn't help me, and trying to transform the equation didn't help either.

I know that $2E \geq \chi \cdot (\chi -1)$. And that $V \geq \chi$

My equation can be transformed to $V^2 \geq 2E \cdot \frac{\chi}{\chi -1}$

Am I close?

Searching I have discovered that my question is a duplicate.
The answer down here is partial, but more beautiful than the answer to the question, which is duplicated, though.

Comment: Sorry, So $E$ is the number of edges right? $V$ is the number of vertices right? why is $2E \geq \chi (\chi-1)$?

Comment: @mathpadawan, Suppose that you have a Graph with $\chi$ as it's chromatic number. That means that there is an edge between some two vertices of different color. $E \geq {\chi \choose 2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case 1. $V \geq 2E$.

Observation. If $G$ is simple, $\binom{V}{2} \geq 2E$. i.e., $V^2-2E \geq V$.

For $\chi=1$, $E=0$, and $G$ is an isolated point.

Now, WMA $\chi\geq 2$. (So, $E>0$)

Then, by the above observations, $1 \leq (\chi-1)\cdot\frac{V}{2E} \leq (\chi-1)\cdot\frac{V^2-2E}{2E}$.

Thus, $(\chi-1)\cdot(V^2-2E)\geq 2E$

$\Leftrightarrow$ $(\chi-1)V^2 \geq 2E\cdot\chi$

$\Leftrightarrow$ $V^2\geq 2E\cdot\frac{\chi}{\chi-1}$.

Case 2. $V<2E$.

Unfortunately, I have no idea for this case.

----Edit.----

Rather than above incomplete proof, I suggest other proof.

Now, add one more condition that $G$ is connected.

Case 1. $\chi\leq 2$. $G$ is bipartite. Most possible number of edges is $E_\max 
 = \lfloor \frac{V}{2} \rfloor \lceil \frac{V}{2} \rceil$. Then,

$\frac{V^2}{V^2-2E} \leq \frac{V^2}{V^2-2E_\max} \leq 2$.

Case 2. $\chi\geq 3$. Since $G$ is connected and $\chi \geq 3$, $V\geq E$. Thus, we can observe that

$1 \leq (\chi-1)\cdot\frac{V}{2E} \leq (\chi-1)\cdot\frac{V^2-2E}{2E}$.

Now, follow my original incomplete proof.

I think that we can do for $G$: not connected.

Comment: Thank you for your attention to the question, looks like you made a typo in case 2 $V \geq E$ Yeah, inconnectivity needs additional treatment, I didn't think about that.

Comment: I think some other idea, that extend Case 1 of the second proof. When $\chi=n$, we can consider $G$ as the $n$-partite graph. Maximum possible number of edges is attained when each partition has similar values, $\approx V/n$. From this, $E_\max \leq n\times \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{V}{n}\times \frac{(n-1)V}{n} = \frac{(n-1)V^2}{2n}$. Thus, we can easily deduce that $\frac{V^2}{V^2-2E}\leq \frac{V^2}{V^2-2E_\max} \leq n = \chi$.

Comment: Sorry, what is $WMA_{\chi}$?

Comment: Abbreviation of 'We may assume'.